# Collisions; Linear Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, friction

Let's say we got a rough surface with friction and there are 2 blocks, the block of the left has initial velocity  and will collide with the block of the right, which is in rest. Consider an elastic colision. 
If the impulse is lower than the static friction, it will stop. If the impulse is greater it will move. But considering it moves, does the static friction makes it move slower than it should? Or Because the impulse is greater than static friction it simply moves and the only thing that makes it Lose energy is kinetic friction?
Imagine the 2nd body is attached with glue, after the collision the 2nd body moves slower then if there was no glue. Right?

Comment: You have used the word "impulse." In physics, this is a technical term referring to the integral of force over a time period: $\int \vec{F}\ dt$. Therefore, the impulse cannot be compared to the friction, which is a force. Impulse can be compared with momentum, because impulse is a change of momentum.

Comment: On top of Bill's comment, by definition in an elastic collision no energy is lost - but in the scenario you describe I am not sure that will be the case.

Answer (score 1):

force is change in impulse over time, so saying that impulse is lower than static friction does not make sense, in the same way that saying that some speed is larger than some acceleration, they are different things.

Impulse from a moving object is transferred to the one at rest through a force, that results in an exchange in momentum. During the interaction the rest mass is subject to two horizontal forces, the contact force of the moving object and the friction force from the table. So the longer the interactions and thus the transfer of momentum, the slower the motion of the mass at rest.

However, in solving those problems you usually assume that the transfer of momentum is almost instantaneous, so the contact forces between masses are very high and the acting time of the friction during the collision very short, and you can ignore the friction force during the collision. If so the object at rest will initially move but will be start to be decelerated by the friction as soon as it starts to move. The case of the glue is an extreme case of friction, in such a case (assuming the mass will not be unglued by the force) you cannot ignore the force made by the glow even if the collision is of short duration, it will ever match the force of the colliding mass and the mass at rest will not move because it will be subject to a zero net force: two  forces of equal magnitude but of opposite directions,

Comment: I understand You. Thank You. But in the case of the glue, I was saying the contact force is greater than the friction(glue), just to give an idea of what I was talking about. A sticky substance that at the moment of collision will let the collision take some time, and thus desaccelerating the right block even more